# Colorful Tverberg’s theorem for special case

Tags: discrete-geometry

(Colorful Tverberg’s theorem by Barany and Larman).
Let $n$ red, $n$ green, and $n$ blue
points be given in the plane. then it is possible to partitions the points into n triples, each consisting of different colors, so that the $n$ corresponding triangles have a common point.

I just want to see that, is there a simple argument for $n=3$?